# HBaseProtos$SnapshotDescription cannot be resolved

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to test simples HBaseAdmin functionalities but when I import the HBaseAdmin class

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
```

I have the error below at the package level :

```
The type org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.HBaseProtos$SnapshotDescription cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

My project use the jars *hbase-common-0.98.0.2.1.1.0-390-hadoop2.jar* and *hbase-client-0.98.0.2.1.1.0-390-hadoop2.jar*.

Have you got any idea about my error ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add protocol jar and protobuf jar. After adding these two jar files to my class path this problem was resolved for me.